# Picasso vs. Setting src to ImageView via XML

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, picasso

Is there a difference between using Picasso to put an image into an ImageView and just using android:src in the xml of the imageview? Right now I have an app that contains about 500 images, and I set them all using android:src in XML. Should I be using Picasso for something like this? Am I wasting precious memory?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso is mainly used to load image from the network. You all your images are resources of your application; you can safely set them in the XML.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there anything I can do to slow down the memory footprint? I resized these images to be smaller than they were originally. Does that help?

Comment: It always helps to have small images but you will lose quality. You can't really do anything, if your app is designed to show all the 500 images in the same screen, the system will have to load in memory all the images. Consider moving to a ListView to display your images. This way, you could reduce the amount of images in memory to only the amount of images currently shown in the List.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may still be some advantages to using picasso even for loading local resources.  I think you would still get the caching which might speed up certain operations.  For example maybe you get a memory cached image when you switch back and forth between two activities, or scroll in and out of view.

The following is from the Picasso web site.  I am thinking Square saw some value in this otherwise I don't know that they would have implemented this.

RESOURCE LOADING

Resources, assets, files, content providers are all supported as image sources.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView2);
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I would get some cache performance improvements. Do you think it's worth implementing?

Comment: If that is the only thing you are using Picasso for, then I don't know, but if you already are using it in your project, then I don't see why not.

Comment: I guess it also matters how these images are loaded.  if you have 500 images, I am sure they are not all displayed at the same time, right?  So if they are in some sort of listview and they are only loaded when they are scrolled into view then I think Picasso might help a lot. What are you doing with these images?

Comment: I have some displayed with a listview, and when you press a list item the respective image is also shown again, albeit larger.